# Laurent series expansion of $\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients, laurent-series

How would one go about determining the Laurent series of such a series as

$$\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}$$

This is tricky since I know its a pole of second order at z = 0 but just unsure what to do past that point. I tried expanding the exponential but it just gives me an infinite series that I do not know how to deal with.

Comment: You're on the right path. From there use geometric series on the infinite series in the denominator.

Comment: So I get $\frac{1}{z^2+z^3/2!+z^4/3!}$ do I then just take the $z^2$ out because I know the answer to the Laurent series is of the form $\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{2z}+a_0 + a_2z^2$

Comment: Find $e^z-1$ multiply by $z$. Finally, inverse it. If you want to inverse it by using summation symbol you can use Cauchy Multiplication: $\sum a_{n} \cdot \sum b_{i} = \sum c_{n-i}$

Answer (score 2):

Apply the Taylor series for $e^z$

$$\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)} = \frac{1}{z^2\left(1+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{6}+\cdots\right)} = \frac{1}{z^2}\left(1-\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{6}-\cdots+\left(\frac{z}{2}+\cdots\right)^2-\cdots\right)$$

$$= \frac{1}{z^2}\left(1-\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^2}{4}+O(z^3)\right) = \frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{2z}-\frac{1}{12}+O(z)$$

by the geometric series formula for $\frac{1}{1+z}$

Comment: Hi thanks for responding but I checked the answer and its $\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{2z} + \frac{1}{12}-\frac{z^2}{720}$

Comment: Im also unsure what exactly happens between the first and second line... I'm sure its obvious but I am just not getting it ! Sorry to be annoying!!

Comment: @PhysicsStudent no worries it is perfectly alright! It's just foiling the lowest order terms and pulling them out.

Comment: @Physics Student just working on $\mathrm{mod x}$, $\mathrm{mod x^2}$,...

Comment: @PhysicsStudent I also caught the mistake but Claude has the correct answer up too

Answer (score 2):

By Taylor
$$z(e^z-1)=z^2+\frac{z^3}{2}+\frac{z^4}{6}+\frac{z^5}{24}+\frac{z^6}{120}+\frac{z^7}{720}+\frac{z^8}{5040}+O\left(z^9\right)$$ Using the long division
$$\frac 1{z(e^z-1)}=\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{2
   z}+\frac{1}{12}-\frac{z^2}{720}+\frac{z^4}{30240}+O\left(z^5\right)$$

If you want the infinite series, just use the fact that
$$\frac 1{e^z-1}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{B_m }{m!}z^{m-1}$$ and divide by $z$.

Comment: ahh so that is correct and it looks like a promising method.  But could you explain by what you mean by long division as I am unsure how to do long division when the denominator is infinitely long.

Comment: It’s exactly the same as what you learned in high-school, except that you must write the monomials in *ascending* order. That applies to top and bottom of the fraction.

Comment: @PhysicsStudent. If you want an infinite number of terms, you need to know what are the coefficients. This is another story. I shall edit.